# Flutter, StreamController is not working on fetching image from network

Tags: dart, stream, flutter

I'm practicing Stream and implemented simple app which fetches image and show to the screen.

Here is my code, but it doesn't show anything why??

I'm studying StreamController and it's usage, so I don't want to use Future or other Widget. This logic worked on simple counter app.

```
class MyAppPageState extends State<MyAppPage> {

  StreamController<List<String>> _controller = StreamController<List<String>>();

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.orange),
        body: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: _controller.stream,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) => 
                Image.network(snapshot.data[0])
          )
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => _addDataToStream()
        ),
      );
    }

    void _addDataToStream() {
      http.get('https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/weekdayList.nhn?week=mon')
        .then((response){
          dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
          final e = document.querySelectorAll('.img_list .thumb');
          List<String> url = e.map((element){
            return element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
              .attributes['src'];
          }).toList();
          _controller.sink.add(url);
      });
    }

    @override
      void dispose() {
        _controller.close();
        super.dispose();
      }
}
```

Comment: `url` has list of strings which mean the source address of image in webpage

Comment: [https://shared-comic.pstatic.net/thumb/webtoon/183559/thumbnail/title_thumbnail_20160516123017_t83x90.jpg, https://shared-comic.pstatic.net/thumb/webtoon/648419/thumbnail/thumbnail_IMAG10_1421195d-13be-4cde-bcf9-0c78d51c5ea3.jpg, https://shared-comic.pstatic.net/thumb/webtoon/602910/thumbnail/thumbnail_IMAG10_ec235b6e-c4fa-47ab-8141-36c4f1572a79.jpg, https://shared-comic.pstatic.net/thumb/webtoon/654774/thumbnail/thumbnail_IMAG10_b85f5350-ca68-4300-ab15-036d9ee060c8.jpg, https://shared-comic.pstatic.net/thumb/webtoon/679519/thumbnail/title_thumbnail_201606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine except with a little error.

When we opened the app for the first time, it'll show a `NoSuchMethodError` like this:

[image]

The reason was that we haven't checked our snapshot if it has already received a data or not.
We can use the `initialData` property to provide some initial data when there's no input from the stream.

```
initialData: <List<String>>[],
```

We also need to write some `if` statements.

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('No Data');

if (snapshot.data.length == 0) return Text('No Data');

return Image.network(snapshot.data[0]);
```

I modified your code and created a BLoC class to be used.

This is the BLoC:

```
//somebloc.dart
import "dart:async";

class SomeBloc {

    final _data = StreamController<List<String>>();
    Stream<List<String>> get data => _data.stream;

    final _url = StreamController<List<String>>();
    Sink<List<String>> get urlIn => _url.sink;
    Stream<List<String>> get urlOut => _url.stream;


    SomeBloc() {
        urlOut.listen(_handleData);
    }

    void _handleData(List<String> urlList) {       
        _data.add(urlList);         
    }

}
```

Modified main:

```
//main.dart
import "dart:async";

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;

import "somebloc.dart"; // the bloc


...

class MyAppPageState extends State<MyAppPage> {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        SomeBloc bloc = SomeBloc();

        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.orange),
            body: Center(
                child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: bloc.data, 
                    initialData: <List<String>>[],
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){

                        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('No Data');

                        if (snapshot.data.length == 0) return Text('No Data');

                        return Image.network(snapshot.data[0]);



                    }
                    )
                ),
           floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
               onPressed: () => _addDataToStream()
               ),
           );
     }

    void _addDataToStream() {

        http.get('https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/weekdayList.nhn?week=mon')
            .then((response){
                dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
                final e = document.querySelectorAll('.img_list .thumb');
                List<String> url = e.map((element){
                    return element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
                       .attributes['src'];
                       }).toList();
                bloc.urlIn.add(url);
            });
    }

}

...
```

If you are interested in using Streams, then I would recommend that you should use the [rxdart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart) package.

```
//somebloc.dart using rxdart
import "package:rxdart/rxdart.dart";
import "dart:async";

class SomeBloc {

    final _data = BehaviorSubject<List<String>>(); // from rxdart
    Stream<List<String>> get data => _data.stream;

    final _url = StreamController<List<String>>();
    Sink<List<String>> get urlIn => _url.sink;
    Stream<List<String>> get urlOut => _url.stream;


    SomeBloc() {
        urlOut.listen(_handleData);
    }

    void _handleData(List<String> urlList) {       
        _data.add(urlList);         
    }

}
```

Here is the result:

[image]